# Make temporary changes to systemd-networkd which go away after reboot, for testing?

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd

`systemd-networkd` is the way to configure a network using systemd. The files live in `/etc/systemd/network`. If I want to change a setting, I can edit a file there, and then do a `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` to load that.

However if I make a mistake, and break my networking, then my SSH connection will die, and I will be unable to log in. I must then reboot the system into a 'rescue mode', and edit the file. Is there anyway to make a networkd change, and apply it, *but only for this boot*? So that if I reboot the server, the old settings will be applied? This would make testing easier.

For example, [`iptables` is/was the firewall confiuration command on Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/iptables). By default it wouldn't save configuration, one had to use `iptables-persistent` command. So you could configure your firewall with `iptables`, and only use `iptables-save` when you wanted to save your settings to a file. If you broke your firewall and locked yourself out, you could just reboot and those unsaved changes were gone.

Is there anything like this for `systemd-networkd`?

This is Ubuntu 18.04, with systemd 237.

Answer (score 3):

Put your .network .link or .netdev units in the volatile runtime network directory `/run/systemd/network/`. Drop in configs are also supported, for example `/run/systemd/network/tunnel.netdev.d/config.conf` Stored in tmpfs, a reboot will delete it and the only out of band command you need is to power off the VM.

Similar config file scheme is common across systemd. Same named files in `/etc/systemd/` have priority over `/run/systemd/`, which in turn have priority `/usr/lib/system/`.